# Mining income calculation - H/s, MH/s or GH/s for hashing power?

Tags: altcoin, mining-profitability, mining-reward

I've seen online calculators use hashing power in H/s, MH/s and GH/s for various algorithms. How does one decide hashing power denomination must be used for mining income calculation? I feel like it has something to do with a specific coin Nethash but I can't figure it out...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: or should I simply convert Nethash as well as user's hashing power into H/s and be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in the hashrate you have \ planning to have. The hashrate depends on the hardware and hash function.

For example, this Bitcoin mining device gives 16 TH/s, which is 16,000 GH/s - https://halongmining.com/shop/dragonmint-16t-miner/.

For GPUs, there are tables online that can give estimates for hashrate of GPU/function combinations, e.g. https://miningchamp.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use H/s, GH/s, TH/s, PH/s doesn't really matter as long as both your numerator and denominator for the calculation uses the same measurement. If your machine is in GH/s then it might be best to convert the network hash rate into GH/s - but like I said, it doesn't really matter as long as you are consistent in your calculation.

*This might not be part of the question but you can find the total hash rate in the network from a service provider such as https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate*

When doing these calculations you should also keep in mind that the total hash power of the network has been increasing consistently over the existence of bitcoin.